# Como substituir 1 bit de um inteiro sem alterar os demais bits vizinhos?

Tags: c, operadores, bit

Quero alterar 1 bit e manter os mesmos valores dos demais bits vizinhos.

O operador de bit desloca para a esquerda ou direita, alterando o bit de 1 par 0, mas ele altera toda a sequência de 8 bits. Eu não queria que isso acontecesse.

Como alternativa, eu altero o próprio número inteiro, com isso o bit que desejo é alterado.

Por favor, alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

se usarmos o XOR com o 1 dá para trocar um bit:

```
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

por exemplo para trocar um 0 para um 4 mudamos o 3º bit.

```
char a = 0x00;
int bit = 2;
a ^= (1 << bit)
```

Comment: Tomás, ele altera o seguinte?  X = 150; //em binário = 10010110.     Sua sugestão altera o último bit de "0" para "1"? Resultando na sequência binária 10010111, que altera o inteiro da  variável X para 151?

Comment: nesse caso seria mais simples fazer `x += 1;`

Answer (score 3):

A linguagem C até permite que façamos o uso de `struct`e `union`  para poder deerminar diretametne o valor de um ou mais bits com o operador `=`. 
Essa funcionalidade é pouco usada -  e de qualquer forma, requer que você defina uma Union dando nomes aos bits (ou campos com tamanhos diferentes de bits).

Para alterar um bit "genérico" em um byte, o mais comum é:

- criar um número com o bit na posição certa
- Usar a operação "|"  ("ou" binário) para setar o bit

Isso se voce quiser passar o bit sempre de 0 para 1. O uso do "xor" sempre vai inverter o bit. E se quiser apagar um bit, então o processo envolve criar uma máscara em que o bit desejado tem o valor "0", e aplicar a operação "&".

Podemos fazer uma função para setar ou resetar um bit que faça isso: receba um ponteiro para o byte a alterar, a posição do bit, e o valor desejado. Criamos o byte com o bit em "1" na posição correta - (usando o operador `<<`), a partir dele criamos uma máscara com esse bit em zero, e aplicamos o bit com o valor enviado. Em C:

```
void altera_bit(char *alvo, char posicao, char valor) {
    char mascara = ~(1 << posicao);
    *alvo = (*alvo & mascara) | (valor << posicao);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos!